# how to disable all div contents using a trasparent div?

Tags: html, css

I have a 3-columns template in my web application.

Imagine that the right-side div is `<div id="right">` In some pages I want to disable all contents in this div using another div that has a transparent background.

How can I do it?

(please tell me your suggestions with a click on `<input type="button" id="btn" value="Disable" />` as a handler)

Comment: Just a useability question - how will the user know if it is disabled if it is transparent? They won't be able to click on anything, but they might just think your site is broken.

Comment: As My Head Hurts says, this is very unintuitive from a UX persepctive. Your visitors would just think their mouse or browser is broken. It would be better to use some client or server side code to actually disable the elements.

Comment: I don't believe it. This is not the only web application that uses this technic. For example, when you are removing your all spams in new Gmail interface, you think that gmail website is broken ? I said transparent, because of preventing this problem.

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood what you meant. Could you add an image representing what you are trying to achieve (before and after)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

`<div id="rigth" style="position: aboslute; left: 999px; top: 10px;">Whatever</div>` -> your style here... I used some random values

`<div id="rigthCover" style="position: aboslute; left: 999px; top: 10px; opacity: 0.3; background: #fff; display: none;">Whatever</div>` -> same as the before one, works in mozilla/chrome, you have to filter opacity for IE (alpha filter, google it you find it fast)

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Disable" onclick="disable()" />
```

Javascript:

```
function disable()
{
      document.getElementById("rightCover").style.display = "block";
}
```